# Sort received dates from response in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, sorting

I am working on code where I am receiving lots of data associated with dates
each object having one date parameter and there might many objects with the same date.

I need to show this all objects in UITableView. each object as one cell.
I succeed in that,
I need to get unique dates from the response array of objects.
Those unique dates will be stored in an array which will act as a number of sections of my table view with section header title will be the date from the unique date array.

somehow I am able to sort out that with what I want,
The only problem I am facing is I am not able to sort the unique date array
every time the sequence change.
I need the latest date as the first date and the oldest date as the end date.

How to achieve this in swift.

Following is a piece of code I have written

```
let sortedKeys = Array(dictValue.keys).sorted(by: {$0 > $1})
print(sortedKeys)
```

here `dicValue.keys` is my unique date array and I wanted to sort it.

Following is a sample response I am getting

```
["08/03/2021”, “10/02/2021”,  "26/04/2021", "25/03/2021”,  "09/12/2020”, , "27/04/2021”,  "23/03/2021”,  "11/01/2021”,  "05/03/2021”,  "09/03/2021”, "16/10/2020", "19/03/2021", "12/10/2020" ]
```

and after applying sort I am getting the following output

```
[“27/04/2021", "26/04/2021", "25/03/2021", "23/03/2021", "19/03/2021", "16/10/2020", "12/10/2020", "11/01/2021", "10/02/2021", "09/12/2020", "09/03/2021", "08/03/2021", "05/03/2021”]
```

where dates are not properly sorted out.
Can anyone please help me out with it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This string date format is inappropriate for sorting, because the most significant component is `day`. Only a date format like `yyyy/MM/dd` can be sorted properly by comparison operator `>`.

However this is Swift. The closure can contain anything as long as it returns a Bool. You could sort the array with a custom sort algorithm. It splits the strings into components and sorts first `year` then `month` then `day`

```
let sortedKeys = dictValue.keys.sorted { (date1, date2) -> Bool in
    let comps1 = date1.components(separatedBy: "/")
    let comps2 = date2.components(separatedBy: "/")
    return (comps1[2], comps1[1], comps1[0]) > (comps2[2], comps2[1], comps2[0])
}

print(sortedKeys)
```

Comment: vadian :- thank you so much for the help, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort a date, just sort a `Date`. `Date` supports `Hashable` and can be used as a dictionary key, you could map your original dictionary and by using a `DateFormatter` to format your string keys into `Date`s then you can easily sort them.

```
let dictionary = ["08/03/2021": 2, "10/02/2021": 5,  "26/04/2021" : 6]
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy" // You should probably adjust other properties of the formatter

let newDict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:
                            dictionary.map { (key, value) -> (Date, Int) in
                                print("Key: \(key)")
                                return (formatter.date(from: key)!, value)
                            })

let sortedDates = newDict.keys.sorted { $0 > $1 }
let value = newDict[sortedDates[0]]
```